# What is and how to use the '<<<END_JAVASCRIPT' string?

Tags: php

I found this code snippet for php:

```
$sJavascript = <<<END_JAVASCRIPT

var callback = arguments[arguments.length-1], 
nIntervalId; 

function checkDone() {
  if( window.MY_STUFF_DONE ) {
    window.clearInterval(nIntervalId); // stop polling
    callback("done"); // return "done" to PHP code
  }
}

nIntervalId = window.setInterval( checkDone, 50 ); // start polling
END_JAVASCRIPT;

$sResult = $session->execute_async(array(
  'script' => $sJavascript,
  'args' => array(),
 ));
```

What is that 'END_JAVASCRIPT' string(?) and how and when should be use? 
P.S. I tried to run this snippet but I get a parse error in PHP ('unexpected $end').

**UPDATE:**
The reason I was getting the parse error is that I indented the code (including the closing identifier 'END_JAVASCRIPT'). The PHP [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) documentation contains the following warning:

> *It is very important to note that the line with the closing identifier must contain no other characters, except **possibly** a semicolon (;). That means especially that the identifier **may not be indented**, and there may not be any spaces or tabs before or after the semicolon. It's also important to realize that the first character before the closing identifier must be a newline as defined by the local operating system.*

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).  Very useful for outputting large chunks of HTML, especially when you're including PHP variable values, because they get interpreted as they do when using double-quotes, but with heredoc you don't have to escape your double quotes.

```
$str = "foo";
echo <<< ARBITRARY_STRING
    <span class="blah">This is the $str var</span>
ARBITRARY_STRING;
```

Pay close attention to the closing `ARBITRARY_STRING;` line, in has to be on a line by itself and cannot have any whitespace at its start or after the semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

It's the [heredoc string literal syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). `<<<SOMETHING` starts a long, multi-line string, and `SOMETHING;` on its own line ends the string.

The reason you got a syntax error is probably because you indented the `END_JAVASCRIPT;` part. It has to be at the very beginning of a line.